# How to create a relative inline style?

Tags: javascript, css

I was looking at the canvas app [The Eatery](https://apps.facebook.com/the-eatery/?ref=bookmarks&fb_source=bookmarks_apps&fb_bmpos=2_) has created and I noticed how the layout is fluid. Specifically the `#main` column's left margin enlarges as the page is widened. I looked through the CSS with Chrome's inspector and I can't see what property is set that starts with a default distance from the left edge, but that grows with the length of the page. There is an  inline style, but I don't understand how it's relative to the width of the window.

I can duplicate it using something like `left:5%;` but I don't think that's what's happening in particular on this page. Because, watching it in the inspector, it's pixel-based sizing and using a percent keeps the percents in the CSS. Any idea what's happening on that page that I can't seem to duplicate?

I've looked through a ton of the fixed-width questions on SO, but none of the answers seem to do it.

Comment: I'm looking at it in FF and I'm not seeing any movement in the left margin of `#main`, so I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding what you are looking at or if it is something only occurring in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, not margin. It's `<div id="main" style="left: 282px;">` where the `left` value changes based on the width of the window.

Comment: It doesn't change for me (stays at 20px), so I guess I'm not going to be much help in solving it :-). Though if it is changing then it must be a script resetting the position as the window is resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's made by javascript onresize event.

In this particular the code is:

```
var a=$(window).width()
b=184;
$("#main").css("left", Math.max( (a-500-600)/2, 20) ), 
    $(window).height() < 800 ?
    ($("#hand, .hand-image").addClass("smaller") , b=96 ) :
    $("#hand, .hand-image" ).removeClass( "smaller" ), $("#app-store").css("right", Math.min(a-850, b ) );
```

-- remove from the source code --

The idea is simple, take the width of document or window and move the div to a position based on the size. In the case, the left value is the higher between `(a-500-600)/2` and 20 (px).

Comment: I figured it was probably JS. Thanks!